# Which one makes sense?

Tags: british-english

I want to tell someone that I have a feeling that started as of the beginning of February and I still have it, so which one is correct and why.

1. > I was having this feeling from/since the very first day of February
2. > I have been having this feeling from/since the very first day of February

Comment: Which of these four options do you think is proper, and what is wrong with the other three? We'll be happy to offer feedback on your own analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I **was having** this feeling as of the first day in February [or first of February] **but now I don't have it anymore**.

2) **I've been having** this feeling as of the first day in February and **still have it**. [focus on the fact this is not necessarily continuous from the time it began and the present; **it could be off and on starting in the past and continuing. Is that clearly expressed?**]

3) **I've had this** feeling since the first of February and it just will not go away. [focus on the fact it started in the past and it still there. It is  not off and on over that time and now.]

2 and 3 are correct. The differences in meaning between 2 and 3 a tricky but true.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

> I've had this feeling since the very first day of February.

*I was having* is rather ungrammatical with *since* (which calls for a perfect tense), and *I have been having* implies a repeated action (or, in other words, that you have had this feeling multiple, separate times). Since you want to say that the feeling has consistently been with you from February, it's better to use Present Perfect Simple.

Comment: It would be better to leave out the *very* in this case, as it is more idiomatic to use the form *very first day…* when talking about, say, when you met your best friend or now-spouse. Spot on with the grammar though!

Comment: @WillCrawford I think it's okay if you want to emphasize that you started feeling like this as soon as February began - for example if something important started or changed with the beginning of February.

Comment: It's *too much* emphasis, unless it's emphatically reaffirming something that's being questioned. I'd say it feels somewhat unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

The first reads a little awkwardly because *was having* is completely in the past, and you say that you *still have it*. With *from* it makes some sense, but isn't what you want to say; *since* is appropriate for something that is still going on.

The second is grammatically fine, but just doesn't sound like conversational English; it sounds like something one might say *to one's doctor*¹ to describe a pain one's *been having*. The other reason it doesn't quite work for the context you describe, is that the *have been having this feeling* suggests a repeated event. Otherwise one would usually just say

> *I **have had this feeling** since…*

or

> *I **have been feeling like this**² since…*

or simply

> *I **have felt like this**³ since…*

As such I would suggest using one of these three; I posted the first but on reflection the third one seems more concise.

¹ Anecdotal evidence, from me.

² [Present perfect continuous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present/present-perfect-continuous-i-have-been-working) from [English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/english-grammar-today/) (Cambridge):

> We use the present perfect continuous for a single activity that began at a point in the past and is still continuing

but please do read the whole page (this *can* also used for repeated events).

³ [Present perfect simple](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present/present-perfect-simple-i-have-worked) from same source:

> We use the present perfect simple to refer to events in the past but which connect to the present

Comment: They are all grammatically fine, the first one is just not complete.